# NSMutableArray shows correct values in log but not in table cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have this mutable array ---> `delegate.addItem_Discount`. First Time i print this mutable array into log `NSLog(@"%@",delegate.addItem_Discount);`

```
2012-06-01 11:56:16.941 TableView with Navigation[4220:f803]
(
    10,
    20,
    30
)
```

I got above print values. and show into table cell successfully.

After this Successful process, i removed one content from this array `[delegate.addItem_Discount removeObjectAtIndex:1];` and print into log again

`NSLog(@"%@",delegate.addItem_Discount);`

```
2012-06-01 11:56:16.941 TableView with Navigation[4220:f803]
(

    10,

    30
)
```

and i got this print into log which shows perfect result. but while i am printing this value into table cell with this code sideLbl_DisAmt.text = [delegate.addItem_Discount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; i am getting in correct values

`10` and `20`.

Although `20` has been removed from my array , there should be print only `10 30`. What is the wrong with me please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its already mentioned here. The problem is only this my array is showing values in log correctly. But while i am showing these values in table cell then i am getting first two old values. See the code above

Comment: yes, I have 3 values in my mutable array[10,20,30] which is showing in log and after removing the object 20 my final array is [10,30] which is also showing in my log successfully. but while i am reloading the table view print again the array in log in table view delegate there also values are showing correctly but print in cell wrong [10, 20]. While 20 has been removed from the array, 20 does not exist any where in the array otherwise it shows in log. I also so confused :(

Comment: When dequeuing your cell did you set the cell.textLabel.text to nil?

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
  [delegate.addItem_Discount removeObjectAtIndex:1];
  [yourTableObject reloadData];
```

and dont forget to hook tableview delegate and datasource

Comment: You are not getting the main point of the bug. If i have three values in my array and i am printing those values successfully but after the deleting any one value among of three values. i am not getting refresh values ..

Comment: I am getting first two values of array index

Comment: Are you not getting the refresh values in your tableview ?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 values in my mutable array[10,20,30] which is showing in log and after removing the object 20 my final array is [10,30] which is also showing in my log successfully. but while i am reloading the table view print again the array in log in table view delegate there also values are showing correctly but print in cell wrong [10, 20]. While 20 has been removed from the array, 20 does not exist any where in the array otherwise it shows in log. I also so confused :(

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can get the exact problem.